# Ehcache 3: Are keys that being written get locked?

Tags: ehcache, ehcache-3

Suppose we have a cache with a [CacheLoaderWriter](https://www.ehcache.org/apidocs/3.3.2/org/ehcache/spi/loaderwriter/CacheLoaderWriter.html), so we are registered to the events: `write` and `writeAll`.

What is the status of these keys at that time?

i.e. If another thread tries to `cache.get(keyThatBeingWritten)`, will it be blocked until the `write()`/`writeAll()` operations exit?

Answer (score 1):

`writeAll()` logically functions like a succession of `write()`, it is entirely possible for one thread to observe some already written data while another thread is still busy executing `writeAll()`.

Regarding `write()`, it will block concurrent reader and writer threads working on the same key if needed for as long as needed to fulfill the Ehcache visibility guarantees.